# Limit in terms of a variable

Tags: limits

Let $a>0$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n+a^n}{2^n+3^n}$ in terms of $a$.
I've managed to show that the limit is $1$  if $a=3$ and $\infty$ if $a>3$. I don't know how to approach $a<3$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$\frac{2^n+a^n}{2^n+3^n}$=$\frac{2^n}{2^n+3^n} +\frac{a^n}{2^n+3^n}$
$=\frac{1}{1+(3/2)^n}+\frac{1}{(2/a)^n+(3/a)^n}$

Also  $a^n$ tends to zero if $|a|<1$.

$a^n$ tends to 1 if $a=1$.

$a^n$ tends to infinity if $a>1$.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve it using your hint.